# How do I power an inverter using a combination of a car and an external battery but limit the current taken from the car to only 100A?

Tags: inverter, current-source, current-limiting, constant-current, high-current

The car in question is a Nissan Leaf, whose 12V "starter" battery is replenished by an onboard DC-DC converter with a maximum safe output of about 100A (this is used as a handy way to tap into the energy of the 400V traction battery using an off-the-shelf 12V inverter).

I wish to use this to power an inverter with loads that can briefly (< 30 seconds) draw up to 170A at the inverter input. I want to use an external 12V battery to supply the remaining 70A.

How would I couple the output from the leaf and the output from the external battery such that the build never draws more than 100A from the leaf? Ideally it should also replenish the external battery using any spare current from the leaf when loads are low.

[Essentially, paralleling the leaf with the external battery will achieve most of the aim since the leaf outputs 13-14V when "on" - it just risks overloading the leaf's DC-DC converter so I just need something between the leaf and the external battery to limit the current to 100A in that path].

Comment: Monitor the votlage and current out of the 12V source from the Leaf and your external battery, and switch on your external battery as requried.

Comment: Whats to stop one battery from trying to charge the other one?

Comment: @RohitGupta Both batteries are lead-acid batteries with a nominal output voltage of about 12V. It's fine if one tries to charge the other one since no harm will be done, but since the one in the leaf will be getting charged by the leaf it's most likely (and desired) that that one will charge the external one since it will have the higher voltage.

Comment: @Puffafish that won't work, I want this system to work automatically. If I stood next to it with a current meter and a switch, I won't be able to react fast enough.

Comment: @LMF5000 I was assuming that there would be an MCU or similar silicon doing the monitoring and controlling as required. Rohit Gupta's idea of having the external battery would be quite good too: have a charge controller charging the external battery at a current limit of 100A, and you'd be away. You just need to design your charging circuit.

Comment: @Puffafish - that's pretty much what I have now, minus the charge controller. I'm having a hard time finding a 100-amp charge controller. Can you give me some pointers in terms of what to look for? It needs to take 13V input, pass it all to the battery as long as current is under 100A, then start dropping voltage to keep current at 100A if the load on the inverter gets too great. Would a solar panel controller work for example?